# BindingSource.Filter maximum length

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter, bindingsource

I am using a BindingSource.Filter property to filter my DataGridView. I would like to ask what is the maximum length or size of this string property?

An MSDN user wrote "Keep the size of the Filter property limited. If it grows to large you might encounter "Stack Overflow" errors, which are very hard to trace back" but he didn't write what is the max. size.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter(v=vs.80).aspx

I am newby in this theme, so any help would be appriciated. Thanks, Zoltan

Comment: just give it a try in your case and remeber the warning ...

Comment: Unfortunatelly i couldn't catch it. This always dies with "Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state."

Comment: than your expression is allready to big - it didn't mean "try" in the "try - catch" sense but in the "give it a try - or test it" sense

Comment: sorry, i've missunderstood it.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem as well when implementing a checked-filter list (similar to Excel column filtering).  The stack overflow appears to be linked to the number of "OR" clauses more than to the overall length of the filter. If I replaced the OR with an IN statement I have filters of over 300,000 characters with no problems.